# How to print input c++ function parameter values automatically

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I was wondering if there is a macro or standard way (for debugging purposes) to automatically print the value of the parameters of a function f, just like `__FUNCTION__` prints/shows the function signature? For example,

```
void foo(int x, string y) {
  cout << __FUNCTIION_ARGS__ << endl;
}
```

should show the values of `x`, and `y`.

If there is no such magic the standard way, is it possible to write a macro/template to do this?

--Update--

Per @jxh's comment, if print inside the function in question is impossible with macro/templates, is it possible to do it automatically on the caller-side, with something like:

```
call(foo,x,y);
```

which prints every parameter value, and behaves the same with `foo(x,y)` *as if* it is called directly in every other aspect? If a value is not printable (e.g. pointers, functions), the wrapper `call` can just print an opaque value such as `<ptr>` or `<noprint>`.

Thanks

P.S. I am using gcc, (and also clang in the future).

Comment: In a word, no. Write it by hand like in the good old days.

Comment: @hyde Thanks. Edited as suggested.

Comment: From using a macro's perspective to print the args, this is easier on the caller side than on the function definition side. However, what do you want to have happen if the type is not "printable"?

Comment: You will probably need to list the arguments (or, any variables, actually), but you should be able to achive something like `DUMP_VARS(x, y);` to output something like `file.cpp:333 funcName x=5 y="string value"` by using a variadic macros and some template helper functions.

Answer (score 5):

My take on it :

```
#include <iostream>

// Dummy parameter-pack expander
template <class T>
void expand(std::initializer_list<T>) {}

// Fun
template <class Fun, class... Args>
typename std::result_of<Fun&&(Args&&...)>::type
call(Fun&& f, Args&&... args) {

    // Print all parameters
    std::cout << "Params : ";
    expand({(std::cout << args << ' ', 0)...});
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Forward the call
    return std::forward<Fun>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// Random test function
int myFunc(std::string const &s, double d, int i) {
    std::cout << s << ' ' << d << ' ' << i << '\n';
    return 57;
}

int main()
{
    // Painless call
    std::cout << call(myFunc, "hello", 3.14, 42) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Params : hello 3.14 42
hello 3.14 42
57
```

Variadic templates are fun !

Comment: @Davidbrcz in fact it's exactly what I had just before (see edits). I'm assuming that a no-op function will be far more easy for the compiler to optimize out than a recursive one.

Comment: I don't care about optimization at this point. I care about code's readability. And your trick makes the code far less readable

Comment: @Davidbrcz depends on who you ask I guess. Anyway, the core of the answer is the `call` function template, printing the parameter pack is an independent task (which can be easily replaced by your version).

Answer (score 1):

There is no macro for printing the arguments, but you can print the function prototype using the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro